# Nested While Loop Is Not Working The Way I would Like To

Tags: python, debugging

I recently started learning Python and I am new here at stack**overflow**.
I have been losing my sleep over the code below. I know the error must be very stupid, but I can't seem to find it :(

**Can someone please help me figure out why my code is not outputting the following:**

```
[
    {"first_name": "Elisabeth", "last_name": "Gardenar", "city": "Toledo", "state": "OH"},
    {"first_name": "Jamaal", "last_name": "Du", "city": "Sylvania", "state": "OH"},
    {"first_name": "Kathlyn", "last_name": "Lavoie", "city": "Maumee", "state": "OH"}
]
```

**Here is my code:**

```
def convert_table(table_data):  


  new_table = []
  user_dict = {}
  row = 1
  i = 0

  while row < len(table_data): 
    while i < len(table_data[0]):
      user_dict[table_data[0][i]] = table_data[row][i]
      i += 1
    new_table.append(user_dict)
    row += 1

  return new_table


table_data = [
    ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
    ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
    ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
    ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
] 


print(convert_table(table_data))
```

**Here is the current output:**

```
[
{'first_name': 'Elisabeth', 'last_name': 'Gardenar', 'city': 'Toledo', 'state': 'OH'}, 
{'first_name': 'Elisabeth', 'last_name': 'Gardenar', 'city': 'Toledo', 'state': 'OH'}, 
{'first_name': 'Elisabeth', 'last_name': 'Gardenar', 'city': 'Toledo', 'state': 'OH'}
]
```

Comment: You need to move user_dict = {} inside the first while loop.

Comment: You may want to invest sometime into learning how to breakpoint your python code using vscode or pycharm-ce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you need to reset both `user_dict` & `i` in the outer loop:

```
def convert_table(table_data):
  new_table = []
  row = 1

  while row < len(table_data):
    user_dict = {}
    i = 0
    while i < len(table_data[0]):
      user_dict[table_data[0][i]] = table_data[row][i]
      i += 1
    new_table.append(user_dict)
    row += 1

  return new_table
```

Comment: Nice! I was just about to post that.

Answer (score 0):

You keep overwriting the same `user_dict`. You should instead create a new one in each iteration of the loop:

```py
while row < len(table_data): 
  user_dict = {}
  while i < len(table_data[0]):
    user_dict[table_data[0][i]] = table_data[row][i]
    i += 1
  new_table.append(user_dict)
  row += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict(zip())` inside a list comprehension where the keys is the first index of table_data and use a for-loop to get the rest of table_data as values:

```
table_data = [
    ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
    ["Elisabeth", "Gardenar", "Toledo", "OH"],
    ["Jamaal", "Du", "Sylvania", "OH"],
    ["Kathlyn", "Lavoie", "Maumee", "OH"]
]

lst = [dict(zip(table_data[0], values)) for values in table_data[1:]]

print(lst)
```

output:

```
[{'first_name': 'Elisabeth', 'last_name': 'Gardenar', 'city': 'Toledo', 'state': 'OH'}, {'first_name': 'Jamaal', 'last_name': 'Du', 'city': 'Sylvania', 'state': 'OH'}, {'first_name': 'Kathlyn', 'last_name': 'Lavoie', 'city': 'Maumee', 'state': 'OH'}]
```